# Making an applet

Tags: java, applet

I have the problem that I am not getting my results, why?

```
public class cycle extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

  Panel panel = new Panel();
  JButton left = new JButton("left");
  JButton right = new JButton("right");
  Container c = getContentPane();

  public void frame() {
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    JButton left = new JButton("left");
    JButton right = new JButton("right");
    c.add(left);
    c.add(right);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Move the ball");
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }

}
```

Comment: Mainly because the code just isn't right. But luckily applets are a dead technology no longer supported by modern browsers so you can just toss that code and do something more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code this way:

- Add the `Button`s to your `JPanel`
- Add the `Panel` to the `ContentPane`
- Add your `cycle` object to the `JFrame`

Here is the modified code

```
public class cycle extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

  private JPanel panel;
  private JButton left;
  private JButton right;
  private Container c = getContentPane();

  public cycle() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    left = new JButton("left");
    right = new JButton("right");
    panel.add(left);
    panel.add(right);
    c.add(panel);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Move the ball");
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f.add(new cycle());

    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }

}
```

Also:

- I would suggest you rename your class `Cycle`, it is a Java convention to start with an upper case.
- Use `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` instead of `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`
- As suggested below in the comments by **Andrew Thompson**: Don't mix Swing & AWT components. (The Panel should be a `JPanel`)

Comment: That`s mean I need work from theory to practice. Thank you. It works, finally! If I have not help it will be take me years to understand it!

Comment: Done it at first!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Cheers, I added it to my answer